# Clicking a button by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click that button, I've tried several ways and I couldn't.

```
<div class="item" data-id="rota_grupo">
   <i class="fal fa-users">
   </i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your chromedriver path to "DRIVER_PATH" and it should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = Service("DRIVER_PATH")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)

button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fa-users")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item[data-id='rota_grupo'] > i.fal.fa-users"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item' and @data-id='rota_grupo']/i[@class='fal fa-users']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```